# Neovim - Encrypt Files like Vim with :X

Tags: neovim, encryption

### Problem

I use **neovim** and I have tried to encrypt my files with `:X` but then this Error Message comes up:

`E492: Not an editor command: X`

---

### Questions

1. Is there any way to do it in **neovim** like you do it in **vim**?
2. Do you know the reason why it only works in **vim** and not in **neovim**?

---

---

#### Last Word

In case you don't know the `:X` vim command:

`:X` is a **vim** command, that lets you encrypt the current file with a password

---

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In neovim, encryption is intentionally removed.
This is the justification: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/85338fe1d5a56f82546e16c305c2048c081771e0, https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/694, and https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/701.

Since that time, vim has chosen to instead greatly improve the encryption with blowfish2 https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/editing.txt#L1538
and xchacha20 with libsodium https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/options.txt#L2527
rather than remove the feature.

Simply put, `:X` is not part of the feature set of neovim.  vim and neovim are different projects which have different feature sets.  It is not possible to have everything.

Comment: not only blowfish2, but also encryption using `libsodium` and `xchacha20`

Comment: thanks, xchacha20 is not mentioned in editing.txt for some reason.
Also vim docs refer to xchacha20 as "medium to strong encryption," I suppose if you require strong strong encryption there is not a good alternative to gpg.

Comment: I was conservative with *medium to strong encryption*, according to libsodium docs, it should offer a real good encryption value

Answer (score 0):

### Q: Is there a way to do it in neovim?

**A:** No, there is not. The `:X` got removed. But there are some alternatives like the [GPG-Plugin](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg).

---

### Q: Why does it only work in Vim and not Neovim?

**A:** Because the old algorithms were insecure and the community voted against the cryptography for **neovim** and then they got removed in [this commit](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/85338fe1d5a56f82546e16c305c2048c081771e0).

---

---

Hope this helped someone who had the same problem like me :)